# What does a rack handler do exactly?

Tags: ruby, rack

What does a rack handler do exactly, i.e. can someone explain in pseudo-code the steps that a rack handler takes to deliver a result for a request?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It processes the HTTP request headers and content, instantiating a Request object. It then passes the Request object through the middleware then to the rack application. The rack application instantiates a Response object and sends it back up through the middleware, and the hander turns it into HTTP response headers and content.

Comment: This is great but I have one more little question. So is the handler technically a server or does the server forward the request to the handler which then responds back to the server?

Comment: It depends on which handler you use. The FCGI handler communicates with the web server over a socket. mod_passenger actually becomes part of httpd or nginx.